# How to generate null in pig latin script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

> I have tried with below code -

```
a = load 'some_loc';
b = foreach a generate '' as first,
null as second,
NULL as third,
'null' as forth;
```

> Could you please tell which one is the correct one or do I have to add
>   something else into this script for null generation.

Comment: Why do you need 4 columns?Why do you need nulls in the last 3 columns?

Comment: I want some fields as null and push into my SQL table for further interaction with UI.

Comment: What does some_loc contain? Format,Delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is the reserved keyword and case insensitive, you can use null or NULL freely.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a, b, c).
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a, null;
```

please refer to 
[Nulls and Pig Latin](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#nulls)

Comment: I think the null is not case sensitive 
"The names of parameters (see Parameter Substitution) and all other Pig Latin keywords (see Reserved Keywords) are case insensitive." https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#case-sensitivity

Answer (score 1):

The following should be ok

```
null as second,
NULL as third,
```